# How do I get back to the visual studio installer on a Macbook Pro after it has been installed?

Tags: visual-studio-2022, visual-studio-mac, visual-studio-mac-2022, visual-studio-installer

How do I get back to the install screen (see image) for Visual Studio 2022 on a MacBook Pro? I'm sure this has been asked and answered, but I can't figure it out to save my life...

[image]

Comment: On Windows, I simply search for the "Visual Studio Installer" application (its actually a separate application from Visual Studio).  I believe you can also go in to the Windows settings and find the installed applications and click on ellipsis for Visual Studio and select "Modify".  I imagine you can do both of these ways on Mac as well (I don't know how Macs work though!).

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the installer from the Visual Studio for Mac download page.
2. Once the download is complete, click the VisualStudioForMacInstaller_<build_number>.dmg to mount the installer, then run it by double-clicking the arrow logo
3. You may be presented with a warning about the application being downloaded from the Internet. Select Open.
4. An alert will appear asking you to acknowledge the privacy and license terms. Follow the links to read them, then select Continue if you agree

the link about this method other to install again for Macbook Pro : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/installation?view=vsmac-2022